# Set up 4 elements in a row and combine them to one element

Tags: html, css, display

I'm trying to align 4 elements in a row.  Which I did using display:inline-block.  I then combined them all into one element (front-page-post-info)so they would all be centered together.  The problem is that I can't edit the margin-top: of each element individually.  For example I want the read more button to be moved a little bit down below all of the images. So I put margin-top:20px; - however that just made all 4 of the elements move down. How can I edit each element individually, and not all of them combined together?

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/s8Lm3hou/2/

css and html

```css
.front-page-post-info {
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;

}
.moretext {
  display:inline-block;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.front-page-shop-image {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:20px;
}
.main-share-button {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:20px;
}
.comments {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
 <div class="front-page-shop-image"><img src="http://knnindia.co.in/themes/frontend/images/icon_comment.gif" /></div>
<div class="main-share-button"><img src="http://knnindia.co.in/themes/frontend/images/icon_comment.gif" /></div>
<div class="comments"><img src="http://knnindia.co.in/themes/frontend/images/icon_comment.gif" /></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add position:relative; and top:Xpx;

https://jsfiddle.net/scorpio777/s8Lm3hou/6/

```
<style>
.front-page-post-info {
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.moretext {
    display:inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right:20px;
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
}
.front-page-shop-image {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20px;
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
}
.main-share-button {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20px;
    position:relative;
    top:30px;
}
</style>

<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
      <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
      <div class="front-page-shop-image">
          <img src="http://knnindia.co.in/themes/frontend/images/icon_comment.gif" />
      </div>
      <div class="main-share-button">
          <img src="http://knnindia.co.in/themes/frontend/images/icon_comment.gif" />
      </div>
      <div class="comments">
          <img src="http://knnindia.co.in/themes/frontend/images/icon_comment.gif" />
      </div>
</div>
```